# C# Download file corrupt

Tags: c#, webclient

Well, Im trying to donwload a file from GitHub using WebClient C# Class but I always get the file corrupted.. this is my code

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/trapped/rotmg_svr/archive/master.zip", @"C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/aa.zip");
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
}

static void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
}
```

//////

```
public static void ReadFile()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/trapped/rotmg_svr/archive/master.zip", @"C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/aa.zip");
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    }

    static void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finish");
    }

    static void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```

Now Im using that code and calling that function Reader.ReadFile(); , file downloads good but nothing is written in console (e.percentage) .
Thanks

Comment: When you download the file by hand (without code), is the file all right?

Comment: Yes it is, will try JustAnotherUser answer

Comment: You should use `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()` instead of `WebClient.DownloadFile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling DownloadFile() before setting up your event handlers. The call to DownloadFile() will block your thread until the file has finished downloading, which means those event handlers will not be attached before your file has already downloaded.

You could switch the order around like so:

```
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/trapped/rotmg_svr/archive/master.zip", @"C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/aa.zip");
```

or you could use DownloadFileAsync() instead, which will not block your calling thread.